# Mouse click starts animation OpenGL/GLUT C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

So basically I need to start the translation when I click right mouse button. It needs to continue animating regardless of state (up or down) while some condition is `true`. So far I have this

```
double tbr, tyg;
    void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
        if(tbr < 2.0 && tyg < 2.0) {
            do {
                tbr+=0.02;
                tyg+=0.02;
                }
            while (0);
            }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
```

But, when I click the mouse button it just does this once, doesn't continue to do so while the condition is true. How can I implement this with `glutIdleFunc()`, `glutMotionFunc()`, `glutPassiveMotionFunc()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    tbr+=0.02;
    tyg+=0.02;
}
while (0); // 0 is false
```

The condition is never True.